# why when I enter zeroes on the left of an integer , c++ borland compiler changes the integer value?

Tags: c++

This code, when I run it on C++ Borland compiler 5.02

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
    int x;
    cin>>x;  
    cout << x;
}
```

When enter `0010` to `x`, the output is `8`? And these for some entries that have zeroes on its left, but not all?

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is deprecated. Use `<iostream>` instead.

Comment: oh , yeah .. it's octal . thank you so much

Comment: @0x499602D2: His compiler was released in 1997. `iostream` didn't exist until 1998.

Comment: @sharth Then he seriously needs a new compiler. lol

Answer (score 5):

In C++:

- Octal numbers have a leading `0`.
- Hexadecimal numbers have a leading `0x`.
- Otherwise, you have a decimal number.

Therefore:

- `0x10` is a hexadecimal number representing 16.
- `010` is an octal number representing 8.
- `10` is a decimal number representing 10.